# why getting the sum of numbers is not equal if I use Enumerable.Range?

Tags: c#

Recently I was playing on CodingGame, normally I use "for" the challenges, but this time I've been using "Enumerable.Range" and something weird happened.

If N = 1001, the value of "result1" should be 250500, but the output was 251502, why?

But when N = 1000, the values of result1 and result2 are equals, why?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = int.Parse("1001");

        var list = Enumerable.Range(2, N);
        long result1 = list.Sum(item =>
        {
            return item % 2 == 0 ? item : 0;
        });
        
        long result2 = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0) result2 += i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.Range` like this

```
   Enumerable.Range(2, 1001)
```

Generates 1001 numbers starting with 2. The second argument is the count of numbers to generate, not the end value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

It's just because the second argument of the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) method is the count of elements but not the upper bound. Therefore the returning sequence is `2 .. 1002`.